# sum records of a grid and show the total in a header value

Tags: acumatica

how to calculate the sum of all volumes and display the total  in the Total volume field as shown below.

[image: Image of the screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we will create on INRegister DAC a Usr decimal field that will hold the value of "Total Volume".

Please note that any DAC extension fields that utilize `[PXDefault]` attribute should have the Persisting check set to `PXPersistingCheck.Nothing` this will prevent errors occuring when trying to save legacy documents within the system.

```
public class INRegisterExtension : PXCacheExtension<INRegister>
    {
        #region UsrTotalVolume
        public abstract class usrTotalVolume : BqlDecimal.Field<usrTotalVolume>
        {
        }
        [PXDBDecimal]
        [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.00", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Volume")]
        public virtual decimal? UsrTotalVolume { get;set;}
        #endregion
    }
```

Next we will create our detail level Usr field which will hold the value of "Volume" within the grid.

```
public class INTranExtension : PXCacheExtension<INTran>
{
    #region UsrVolume
    public abstract class usrVolume : BqlDecimal.Field<usrVolume>
    {
    }
    [PXDBDecimal]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.00", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Volume")]
    public virtual decimal? UsrVolume { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Finally we will create a `PXGraphExtension` which will append the `[PXFormula]` attribute to our child Usr field allowing the calculations you desire *specifically in the context of this data entry screen*.

If a formula is included on a DAC it's logic is called whenever the DAC is utilized ( GI, Reports, Ect ) thus we add it on a Graph Extension so we are only utilizing logic when needed, i.e. on the data entry page.

```
public class INTransferEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<INTransferEntry>
{
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<INRegisterExtension.usrTotalVolume>))]
    protected virtual void __(Events.CacheAttached<INTranExtension.usrVolume> e)
    {
    }
}
```

Results seen below :

[image: Inventory Transfer Vaolume]

Comment: Thank you for this. So correct.
But I found out that the volume should be the unit volume multiplied by the Quantity.
The volume displayed is the unit Volume. 
so it should be> Volume = unit volume(currently wat is displayed) * Quantity
Kindly assist on this

Comment: If you could update your question I can update the answer to reflect the question. Or you can mark the current answer accepted and find explanation below.

Short: You would need to add an additional field that would hold the value of your "Volume" the Formula attribute would then be moved to this field with the following decleration. [PXFormula(typeof(Mult<INTran.qty,INTranExtension.usrUnitVolume>), typeof(SumCalc<INRegisterExtension.usrTotalVolume>))]